# display get_content from custom post type after custom fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I created my own shortcode to display the data from a custom post type.
I´m able to display the different car types with the custom values on my page. But my CPT also supports an editor(WPBakery Page Builder) where the admin is able to add/customize extra content for every single car. (additional information).

**My problem:**

I want to add/display the content of the editor (=> the_content) below the custom fields. But as soon as I output "the_content" it will appear at the top of my page for every type of car. I can use "get_the_content" to display the data at the correct location ('.$content.') but it won´t include any format and pictures won´t be displayed, instead it outputs the whole img-tag + information.

Is there some way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

**output with the_content()**

[image]

**output with get_the_content()**

[image]
**Shortcode which displays the content on my page:**

```
<?php
if(!defined('ABSPATH')){
   exit;
}

add_shortcode('fahrzeuge', 'display_fahrzeuge');

function display_fahrzeuge($atts, $content = null) {

$output = '';

$args = array(
'post_type'   => 'fahrzeuge',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'tax_query'   => array(
 array(
    'taxonomy' => 'Fahrzeugtypen',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => 'kommandofahrzeuge')));

$output.= '';
$kommandofahrzeuge = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $kommandofahrzeuge->have_posts() ) :
   while( $kommandofahrzeuge->have_posts() ) :

    $kommandofahrzeuge->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $taktischeBezeichnung = esc_html(get_post_meta($post_id,'ff_ried_fahrzeuge_taktischeBezeichnung', true));

    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id,'full'); 

    $output.='
    <div>'.$taktischeBezeichnung.'</div>
    <img class="fahrzeugeFeaturedImage" src='.$featured_img_url.'></img>
    <div>'.$content.'</div>
    ';        

  endwhile;

  wp_reset_postdata();

else :
  esc_html_e( 'Keine Fahrzeuge gefunden', 'text-domain' );
endif;

echo $output;   
}

?>
```

Comment: Use `do_shortcode( $content )` to preserve the shortcode formatting

Comment: Sorry i wasn´t able to solve the problem with your solution but I found a different way. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Inserted this function into the the functions.php

```
function get_the_content_with_formatting ($more_link_text = '(more...)', $stripteaser = 0, $more_file = '') {
    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

**display the formatted content:**

```
$content = get_the_content_with_formatting();
echo $content;
```